# awk or sed replacing specific $3 with ajacent $2

Tags: sed, awk

File looks like

```
$1    $2      $3

Text  Text2    *

Text  Text4    Text3
```

I would like to search for `*'s` within a file and replace the with the text in the column next to it. While keeping the rest of the info... basicly replace the `*` logicaly with column 2.

Currently I am working with either sed or awk

`awk :  awk '{ if($3=*) {print$2}}'`   works... but I would like to keep $1,2 aswell

`sed : sed -r 's/[*]//g'`  I can't get reg expression to replace with $2 properly

Any quick help, tips or tricks?

Comment: Thank you! :D  I enjoy the command line and will keep it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contents of `file.txt`:

```
Text Text2 *
Text Text4 Text3
```

One way using `awk`:

```
awk '$3 == "*" { $3=$2 }1' file.txt
```

Results:

```
Text Text2 Text2
Text Text4 Text3
```

Comment: Both your answers helped me to write  awk '{ if($3=="*") {$3=$2} {print $0}}'  >  file.txt        Could one of you explain the "1" you have that allows a print of the line I have never seen that.

Comment: In `awk`, `1` after the braces is simply shorthand for `print $0`.

Comment: Awesome, I know the basics and seem to write a little long handed. good trick

Answer (score 2):

awk solution:

```
awk '$3=="*"{$3=$2}1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed `\S` and `\s` can be used to represent non-space and space respectively, so you could accomplish what you want like this:

```
sed -r '/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\*/ s//\1 \2 \2/'
```

The empty `s///` command implicitly uses the matches from `//`.

If it is run on the input listed by *steve*:

```
sed -r '/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\*/ s//\1 \2 \2/' file.txt
```

Output:

```
Text Text2 Text2
Text Text4 Text3
```

If you want to preserve inter-column whitespace use:

```
sed -r '/(\S+)(\s+)(\S+)(\s+)\*/ s//\1\2\3\4\3/'
```